# FreeBSD: Partition with Multiple Mount Points

Tags: mount, partition, freebsd, system-installation

On the latest FreeBSD installation, how can I make a partition have both `/var/` and `/tmp/` as a mount point? That is, one partition would contain `/var/` and `/tmp/`. Is that even possible? I know of course that a mount point of / will contain everything not specified, but can I specifically say `/dev/ad0p3/` has `/tmp/` and `/var/` as a mount point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these 2 techniques for doing this. They're highlighted in this post titled: [Mount multiple directories to the same partition?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=94693).

#### Method #1

Boot from another system (e.g. a LiveCD) and mount your `/var` partition and do this as root:

```
cd /mnt/var
mkdir -m755 .newvar
mv * .newvar # won't try to move .newvar because it begins with a period
mv .newvar var # rename .newvar to var
mkdir -m1777 tmp # make a tmp dir
```

Now specify a mountpoint for the entire partition in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/mnt/ignore_me/var /var none bind
/mnt/ignore_me/tmp /tmp none bind
```

#### Method #2

Keep mounting the `/var` partition as you are currently, but do this as root:

```
cd /var
mkdir -m1777 .tmpdir # make a hidden /var/.tmpdir
```

**NOTE:** notice that `/var/tmp` is something different.

Add the following to your /etc/fstab, after the lines that mount /var:

```
/var/.tmpdir /tmp none bind
```